# map by searching in two lists

Tags: python, dictionary, mapping

I want to do a mapping.

I have two lists from which to extract the info and do the mapping.

If we don't find the available entries from the first list, we check the second list.

The first list is `a` and the second is `b`.

```
stuff_types = {
    "spana": {
        "type": "BOOK",
    },
    "geom": {
        "type": "GLASS",
    }
    }

def the_mapping(the_type):
    for key in stuff_types.keys():
        if key in the_type:
            the_type = key
            break
    
    return stuff_types[the_type]

a = ['kal', 'khp', 'khp', 'khp', 'geom']
b = ['hlian', 'spana', 'piper', 'meli', 'phin']

the_list = []
for the_type in a:
    try:
        crop_mapping = the_mapping(the_type)
        the_list.append(crop_mapping)
    
    except:
        try:
            for the_type in b:
                crop_mapping = the_mapping(the_type)
                the_list.append(crop_mapping)
        except KeyError:
            print("\nCouldn't find it!")
            
            
print(the_list)
```

The result now is:

`[{'type': 'GLASS'}]`

but I want:

`[{'type': 'GLASS'}, {'type': 'BOOK'}]`

since I have in list `b` the `spana` word.

** UPD **

If we have:

```
stuff_types = {
    "spana": {
        "type": "BOOK",
    },
    "geom": {
        "type": "GLASS",
    },
    "hlian": {
        "type": "POT",
        }
    }
```

and we run:

```
the_list = [v for k, v in stuff_types.items() if k in set(a + b)]
```

it gives:

```
[{'type': 'BOOK'}, {'type': 'GLASS'}, {'type': 'POT'}]
```

Can we have also the right order?

```
[{'type': 'POT'}, {'type': 'BOOK'}, {'type': 'GLASS'}]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not merge the lists to one?

```
the_list = [stuff_types[the_type] for the_type in a + b if the_type in stuff_types]
```

or

```
the_list = [v for k, v in stuff_types.items() if k in set(a + b)]
```

Edit:

To use merged lists index wise you need another loop. This will keep the order of the items from the new list

```
the_list = [stuff_types[x] for tup in zip(a, b) for x in tup if x in stuff_types]
```

Comment: Can we have an ordered set? Because the order matters in my case.

Comment: @George so you want the items from `b` and than the items from `a`?

Comment: You can use the first solution, just swap the order of the lists to `b + a`

Comment: I want to check item by item. First, item from a, then first item from b. So, first check if `kal` is present, else check if `hlian` is present. Then check if `khp` is present, else if `spana` is present.

Comment: I guess we have to use something like: `d = list(map(lambda x: x, zip(a, b)))` and search there? But still i am not sure about the order.

Comment: @George It's the same as `list(zip(a, b))`, but yes, updated my answer.