# search two lists and fill with None for each pair in correct order

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

This is a continuation from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77402021/map-by-searching-in-two-lists/77402100?noredirect=1#77402100).

Right now, the result is:

```
[{'type': 'POT'}, {'type': 'BOOK'}, {'type': 'GLASS'}]
```

I want, if a key is not found, to insert a `None` in the results.

So, I want:

```
[{'type': 'POT'}, {'type': 'BOOK'}, None, None, {'type': 'GLASS'}]
```

If I try:

```
stuff_types = {

    "spana": {
        "type": "BOOK",
    },
    "geom": {
        "type": "GLASS",
    },
    "hlian": {
        "type": "POT",
        }
    }


a = ['kal', 'khp', 'khp', 'khp', 'geom']
b = ['hlian', 'spana', 'piper', 'meli', 'phin']


the_list = []
for tup in zip(a, b):
    for x in tup:
        if x in stuff_types:
            the_list.append(stuff_types[x])
        else:
             the_list.append(None)
            
print(the_list)
```

just to append `None` , we receive `None` for each one element of the pairs:

```
('kal', 'hlian')
('khp', 'spana')
('khp', 'piper')
('khp', 'meli')
('geom', 'phin')
```

I want to receive `None` in the correct position for each pair not each element in the pair.

Comment: Please update your question with the actual output that you see now, plus the output you really want to see.

Comment: @quamrana: I already have this information in the beginning.

Comment: So what you want is that if neither part of the pair matches then `None` should be chosen? So, a search for the first match with a default of `None`? This looks like a standard search algorithm that should `break` when an item is found and insert `None` at the end ( when no search step triggered the `break`). Or even just a series of `dict.get`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why dict.get(key) instead of dict\[key\]?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11041405/why-dict-getkey-instead-of-dictkey)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
stuff_types = {

    "spana": {
        "type": "BOOK",
    },
    "geom": {
        "type": "GLASS",
    },
    "hlian": {
        "type": "POT",
        }
    }


a = ['kal', 'khp', 'khp', 'khp', 'geom']
b = ['hlian', 'spana', 'piper', 'meli', 'phin']
```

There is a slight modification you don't need a nested for loop:

```
the_list = []
for k,v in zip(a, b):
    if k in stuff_types:
        the_list.append(stuff_types[k])
    elif v in stuff_types:
        the_list.append(stuff_types[v])
    else:
        the_list.append(None)

print(the_list)

#output
[None, {'type': 'BOOK'}, None, None, {'type': 'GLASS'}]
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to test each of the items from `tup` to see if either has a relevant key:

```py
stuff_types = {

    "spana": {
        "type": "BOOK",
    },
    "geom": {
        "type": "GLASS",
    },
    "hlian": {
        "type": "POT",
        }
    }

def make_value(x,y):
    return stuff_types[x] if x in stuff_types else stuff_types[y] if y in stuff_types else None

a = ['kal', 'khp', 'khp', 'khp', 'geom']
b = ['hlian', 'spana', 'piper', 'meli', 'phin']


the_list = []
for (x,y) in zip(a, b):
    the_list.append(make_value(x,y))
            
print(the_list)
```

Output as requested:

`[{'type': 'POT'}, {'type': 'BOOK'}, None, None, {'type': 'GLASS'}]`

Comment: How about `return stuff_types.get(x) or stuff_types.get(y)` as a simplification? I know it is not strictly the same thing, but given the data the result should be the same.

Answer (score 1):

With single traversal, basing on `set` intersection:

```
res = [stuff_types[s.pop()] if (s := set(stuff_types) & set(p)) else None 
       for p in zip(a, b)]
print(res)
```

---

```
[{'type': 'POT'}, {'type': 'BOOK'}, None, None, {'type': 'GLASS'}]
```